# Calculus Question: Improper integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{x-e^{2x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

I am curious about evaluation of the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}e^{x-e^{2x}}dx$$
Is it possible to evaluate it? This not my homework but I will share my attempt. I tried standard technique, integration by part but without any success. I also couldn't find  any suitable substitution. The integral seems as if it were evaluating the expected value or moment generating function of a certain distribution but I couldn't find any pdf like the integrand in my textbook table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax-e^x}~dx=\Gamma(a).~$ Then, after substituting $x=2t$, differentiate twice with

regard to *a*, and let $a=\dfrac12$.

Comment: @Venus: Are you familiar with the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) ?

Comment: Yes but I've never known that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax-e^x}~dx$ is a gamma function

Comment: I get it, let $u=e^x$